# Excel - How to vlookup to return multiple values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm looking to use Excel to look up and return multiple reference values for a given key. **VLookup** does something very similar to what I need - but only returns a single match.

I assume it'll involve array-returning and handling methods, though I haven't dealt with these before. Some Googling starts to lean on the if([lookuparray]=[value],row[lookuparray]) as part of a solution - though I can't get it to return a single match...

For example, if I have this reference data:

```
Adam    Red
Adam    Green
Adam    Blue
Bob     Red
Bob     Yellow
Bob     Green
Carl    Red
```

I'm trying to get the multiple return values on the right. (Comma separated, if possible)

```
Red      Adam, Bob, Carl
Green    Adam, Bob
Blue     Adam
Yellow   Bob
```

(I already have the key value on the left - no need to pull out those values)

Any help as to how to approach handling multiple values in th this context is apprecited. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you want a formula approach as stated (not using VLOOKUP, but still a formula), here is how I laid out the data:

[image: Data Layout]

I then used the following formula in cell C12:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$8, SMALL(IF($B12=$B$2:$B$8, ROW($B$2:$B$8)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$8))+1, ""), 1))
```

This is an array formula so after you copy and paste it into the cell you have to hit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. I then just dragged it to the right and to the bottom.

If there is no value(s) remaining it gives the `#NUM!` error, I gave an example for yellow in the uploaded image example.

I think a VBA/Macro approach would be a better solution if you have tons of rows.

Comment: For those looking to sum values retrieved (where order does not matter), it's simpler to use IF with an array: `=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$8="Key", $C$2:$C$8, 0))`

Comment: I tried this formula but the output i am getting after dragging across and below only returns Adam and Bob - am i doing something wrong? See screenshot here https://snag.gy/qW7UKM.jpg

Comment: @ziggy did you hit ctrl+shift+enter?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the VBA solution for you. First, this is what the results look like:

[image: Screenshot]

And here's the code:

```
Option Explicit
Function LookupCSVResults(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String

    Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
    Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
    Dim r As Long   'Row
    Dim c As Long   'Column
    Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

    s = strDelimiter
    For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
            If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
                'I know it's weird to use offset but it works even if the two ranges
                'are of different sizes and it's the same way that SUMIF works
                sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
                If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                    s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Now make it look like CSV
    s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, ",")
    If Left(s, 1) = "," Then s = Mid(s, 2)
    If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    LookupCSVResults = s 'Return the function

End Function
```

Comment: For general instructions,  see [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)

Answer (score 5):

1. Swap columns so that colors are in column A and names are in column B, and then sort on the color.
2. Formula in C2 (copy it down the column):  =IF(A2<>A1,B2,C1 & ", " & B2)
3. Formula in D2 (copy it down the column):  =A2<>A3
4. Filter for "TRUE" on column D to get desired results.  See below:

[image]

Comment: TIL you can use the "&" operator instead of the clunky CONCATENATE() formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a formula approach then it's much simpler to get the results in separate cells, so lets assume that your first table is A2:B8 and the colours are listed again in D2:D5. Try this formula in E2

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$8=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-ROW($B$2)+1),COLUMNS($E2:E2))),"")`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and copied across and down. When matches run out you get blanks.

Formula assumes Excel 2007 or later - if earlier version you can use COUNTIF instead of IFERROR, i.e.

`=IF(COLUMNS($E2:E2)>COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,$D2),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$8=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-ROW($B$2)+1),COLUMNS($E2:E2))))`