# Dragging the index formula down when using arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

On [this](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values) older page, Dan O'Day provides and excellent excel formula to assist with looking up and returning multiple reference values for a given key in separate columns. The formula is:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$8, SMALL(IF($B$12=$B$2:$B$8, ROW($B$2:$B$8)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$8))+1, ""), COLUMN(A1)))
```

However, I'm finding that I cannot drag the formula *down* to other columns because the arrays prevent the formula from recognizing the new cell, specifically after

```
SMALL(IF($B$12
         ^^^^^
```

I can drag across columns but not vertically. Other than going into each new vertical cell and adjusting the cell number in the formula, how can I drag the formula down so it automatically updates with the new cell information?

Answer (score 2):

It's the `COLUMN` function at the end you need to change if you want to copy the formula down rather than across - you can use `ROW` like this

=INDEX($C$2:$C$8,SMALL(IF($B$12=$B$2:$B$8,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$8))+1),**ROW(A1)**))

or it's actually more "robust" to use `ROWS` function so if first formula is in **D3** use this version copied down

=INDEX($C$2:$C$8,SMALL(IF($B$12=$B$2:$B$8,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$8))+1),**ROWS(D$3:D3)**))