# Values in a column to rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, lookup

I am trying to turn a the table on the left side to the one on the right.

[image: vlookup based on multiple criteria]

How can it be achieved? I have tried [This](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values), but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `I2` you should write this array formula (enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MATCH(1,($G2=$A$2:$A$9)*(H2=$B$2:$B$9),0))
```

Then you can copy it to other columns (K, M, O).

[image: array formula, index, match, multiple criteria]

Comment: Using the formula I get N/A but the result is correct as seen here: https://imgur.com/a/6Ttan4K

Comment: Do you see curly braces in my screenshot? `{ }` ? That is what you get when you actually use Ctrl+Shift+Enter and not simply Enter ;)