# How to vlookup to return multiple values using a "contains type" match, where the search string can appear anywhere in the lookup value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

part of this answer was already done by https://stackexchange.com/users/4784285/engineer-toast on the question done by asked Jan 14 '13 at 21:43 by https://superuser.com/users/22950/overflew on [Excel - How to vlookup to return multiple values?](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values).

With the VBA code provided by engineer-toast I am able to look for the values and get all linked issues inside same cell separated by commas.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yUKc.jpg)
This means that searching for Blue I will get in one cell this result « Adam,John,Mark,Paul », because those were the lines that matched Blue. This means that the VBA function is looking for a perfect match between my search key «Blue» and the cells that match. But I need to be able to search inside a cell. Instead of searching for an exact match I need to match a cell that contains my key. Picking the example above, my key would be «Blue» to match a cell that contains Blue e.g. «Green, Blue, Red» and giving the result « Adam,John,Mark,Paul ». See image with example.[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwdpL.png).

I am new to VBA code so honestly I don't know yet how to change the code provided by engineer-toast user in order to match a cell that contains my key instead of just matching the one's that are equal.

engineer-toast code:

```
Option Explicit
Function LookupCSVResults(lookupValue As Variant, lookupRange As Range, resultsRange As Range) As String

Dim s As String 'Results placeholder
Dim sTmp As String  'Cell value placeholder
Dim r As Long   'Row
Dim c As Long   'Column
Const strDelimiter = "|||"  'Makes InStr more robust

s = strDelimiter
For r = 1 To lookupRange.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To lookupRange.Columns.Count
        If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
            'I know it's weird to use offset but it works even if the two ranges
            'are of different sizes and it's the same way that SUMIF works
            sTmp = resultsRange.Offset(r - 1, c - 1).Cells(1, 1).Value
            If InStr(1, s, strDelimiter & sTmp & strDelimiter) = 0 Then
                s = s & sTmp & strDelimiter
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

'Now make it look like CSV
s = Replace(s, strDelimiter, ",")
If Left(s, 1) = "," Then s = Mid(s, 2)
If Right(s, 1) = "," Then s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

LookupCSVResults = s 'Return the function

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to say that `lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value` **contains** `lookupValue` then replace:

```
If lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value = lookupValue Then
```

with:

```
If Instr(lookupRange.Cells(r, c).Value, lookupValue) > 0 Then
```

If you want it to be the other way aroiund, just switch the position of the `Instr()` arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works very well :)