# VLOOKUP only returns the first column of the columns that I specify

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

[image]

I'm asking VLOOKUP to return the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th columns in a match. It only returns the 2nd column.

Comment: What version of Excel?  Works fine for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kXGJ.png

Comment: Windows 10 Microsoft Excel 2019 MSO (16.0.13801.20288) 64-bit

Comment: Did you remember to CSE?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same regardless of pressing just Enter or CSE

Comment: Lord only knows.  The new spill functionality is an unholy mess as it breaks all sorts of old sheets and it is hard to know what is supported in what version.  I wish you luck.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Somebody on a different forum told me to drag the formula over the adjacent cells, and now it works. I've never had to do that before. Usually hitting enter after a VLOOKUP makes it spill over automatically.

Comment: @gallardoelise, sometimes it doesn't works when you drag it,,, do in this way ,,, enter formula in `I1` then finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`,,, drag formula RIGHT,, press `F2` (selecting I1:k1),, and again finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` ,, will work without failure !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel - How to vlookup to return multiple values?](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter is your need.

Comment: The issue is that I was using O365, where VLOOKUP spilling over is standard behavior. This behavior does not occur on Excel 2019.